# Find criteria in multiple columns, and sum an offset of each matched value

Tags: excel, offset, sumifs

I need to get a total sum of values from multiple columns based on a criteria a set amount of columns away from each value.

For example:

```
Column 1   Column2      Column3  Column4    Column5      Column6
Staff 1                          staff2
status --- location --- cost     status --- location --- cost
g          london       500      y          manchester   250
y          birmingham   450      g          scotland     100
```

I want to sum all the costs where the status is "g".
I've been trying to sum, sumif, sumifs, sumproduct, offset and find, I'm just not sure of the correct combination of functions to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: want to sum all the costs where the status is "g"...is it for all staff??? how many staff do you have, will the staff no increase/decrease????

Comment: Hi Vasim, thanks for your reply. Yes its for all staff, and there are about 15, and one may be added every few months or so but I can just adjust formulas in that case. the spreadsheet is laid out like a giant calander with 365 dates down the far left hand 1st column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

**=SUMPRODUCT((A:A="g") * (C:C))+SUMPRODUCT((D:D="g") * (F:F))**

Comment: Thanks man, equires a lot of copy/pasting to cover each staff member but it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler to use a `SUMIF` formula with the sum range offset 2 columns from the criteria range - then you can use one single `SUMIF` function for all columns, e.g.

`=SUMIF(A:HZ,"g",C:IB)`